# Recorrer array fila por fila en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="textleft",limit=30):
    a = link.find('a').attrs['href']
    print(a)
```

esto me devuelve 30 objetos:

```
/HORTICHUELAS-N-4812.html
/ISABEL-ALONSO.html
/TRANS-CEREZUELA.html
/NATURE-CHOICE.html
/AGRUPA-INVER.html
/HERBEX-IBERIA.html
/HORTOFRUTICOLA-NORIAS-ALMERIA.html
/GARCIDEN.html
/CASUR.html
/HORTOSABOR-MEDITERRANEO.html
/GRUPO-CONTROL-EMPRESA-SEGURIDAD.html
/VEGACANADA.html
/ONDUSPAN.html
/EJIDOMAR-AND.html
/ENZA-ZADEN-ESPANA.html
....
...
```

asi hasta 30 resultados como puedo ir metiendo cada resultado en una variable , iterando con cada uno de los resutados uno por uno por ejemplo

```
var 1 = /SOTRAFA.html
var 2 = /AGROPONIENTE.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mejor manera es definir un array e ir añadiendo a cada posición el contenido. Por ejemplo:

```
variables = [] 

for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="textleft",limit=30):
    variables.append(link.find('a').attrs['href'])

print(variables)
```

Comment: me saca muchos resultados no es lo que busco

Comment: Entonces, no acabo de entender lo que buscas.